# If $A_i$ is a set, what does $\bigcap^n_{i=1} A_i$ mean?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory, notation

If $A_i$ is a set, what does $\bigcap^n_{i=1} A_i$ mean? I'm not sure what the upper and lower bounds on the intersection symbol means.

Comment: Do not be discouraged by the downvotes. Honestly, this question does not merit any downvotes.

Answer (score 2):

It means$$A_1\cap A_2\cap\ldots\cap A_n.$$In other words, it's the intersection of the sets $A_1,A_2,\ldots,A_n$.

Comment: Just a quick question, if Ai...An are all subsets of some set B. Would the intersection of all of them be the empty set?

Comment: Why? Suppose that $B=\mathbb R$, that $n=2$, that $A_1=\{0,1\}$ and that $A_2=\{0,2\}$. Then their intersection is $\{0\}$.